# While writing data in MySQL through PHP, add current date and time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm gathering some info from a website to put it in a MySQLdatabase. At this moment I just cannot find out how to get the date and time in the database.

I tried several things, can you help?

```
$write="REPLACE INTO `".$database."`.`db`     (`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`datetime`) VALUES     ('".$1."','".$2."','".$3."','".$4."','".$5."','".$6."','".$7."','**SO WHAT DO I NEED TO PLACE HERE**')";
echo $write;
$query = mysql_query($write) or die (mysql_error());
```

In the database itself no matter what I put in my php, is 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

just passed value `NOW()`, example

```
INSERT INTO tb(col1) VALUES(NOW())
```

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I did try NOW, but it still gives me all those zero's.

Thanks for the injection thing, I will look into that as soon as the time is working ;)

Comment: are you wrapping `NOW()` with single quotes? what is the data type of your column?

Comment: The column is DATETIME.

(don't hit enter for the next line :( )

Without quotes I get an error: NOW does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: I see it's working there, but there are some differences there and in my code :) I'm not sure I can use that whole thing in my code?

Comment: it should be `NOW()` not `NOW`

Comment: IT WORKS! I added a space where it shouldn't be! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

if it's fine to use server's current date/time then use `NOW()` function